# I want to display decimal value in en-us currency format in ASP.NET MVC TextboxFor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

```cs
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Value, "{0:N2}",
                 new { @data_val_number = "The field value must be a Number." })
```

`value = 1182519.13` in edit mode, I want to display `1,182,519.13`

Comment: if your data type is decimal or double,it is correct

Comment: DisplayFormat attribute [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N2}")] to the property in your model that holds the value you want to display in currency format.